# Salesforce SDK from android - How can I refresh my session?

Tags: android, session, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I'm using the Salesfroce SDK on both my native iOS app and Android app.
I'm trying to cover a scenario in which the user loses his session and I want to re-login him without going through the login screen again.

I found the proper solution in iOS:

```
SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().loginWithCompletion({ (authInfo : SFOAuthInfo!) -> Void in
        print("successfuly re-authenticated")
        if (!NSThread.currentThread().isMainThread) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.loadLoggedInWebView()
            })
        }
        else {
            self.loadLoggedInWebView()
        }
    }) { (authInfo : SFOAuthInfo!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        print("re-authenticated failed")
}
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the Android alternative for code. 
What is the correct way of doing this in Android?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got from Salesforce SDK.

[SalesforceSDK OAuth2.java](http://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/blob/master/libs/SalesforceSDK/src/com/salesforce/androidsdk/auth/OAuth2.java)
call one of these methods with required parameters

```
public static TokenEndpointResponse refreshAuthToken(
            HttpAccess httpAccessor, URI loginServer, String clientId,
            String refreshToken) {....}
//AND

public static TokenEndpointResponse refreshAuthToken(
            HttpAccess httpAccessor, URI loginServer, String clientId,
            String refreshToken, String clientSecret) {......}
```

and the result `TokenEndpointResponse.authToken` is your new auth token.
**Important** : If above call throws `OAuthFailedException` means refresh token is not valid (revoked)

Comment: Thanks.
Although should I do with the authToken? 
In other words - what do I update in the Salesforce SDK?

Comment: getting new auth token means refreshing your session.. with this new token web service wont throw AuthError ie  401 status code..

Comment: Ok. the flow now seems clear.
I now understand that this 
SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().getUserAccountManager().getCurrentUser().getRefreshToken();

And I get "null".

What could cause my refresh token to be revoked?

Comment: visit https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_revoke_token.htm&language=en_US

Comment: If you know any  iOS methods to refreshauthtoken, can you please share it.

Comment: @Mahi I am not good with iOS. but you can dig here https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/master/libs/SalesforceSDKCore/SalesforceSDKCore/Classes/OAuth

Comment: @skadoosh - Thanks man, I was searching in CSFRefresh classes. You directed me to the right place. I wish I can give you a cookie.